# updating cache is updating my database fields. how to restrict it. I am using guava with java

Tags: java, guava

I am using Java8 with guava. 
I am caching my tables.
while trying to manipulate some datafields from cache, i am able to get the required response object but the same values are getting persisted in my database table as well.

Not sure how i can restrict it. Is there any strategy that can be defined to make caching unidirectional as only select and no update.

or if some property to define while updating the fields, which would prevent it from syncing to DB

```
public void postConstruct(){
    Cache<Long,Long> myCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
            .maximumSize(2000)
            .expireAfterWrite(15,TimeUnit.Minutes)
            .build();
}
```

Implementation -

```
public void pollAndUpdate(){

Map<Long,Long> myCacheTemp=new HashMap<>();
//Transform cache map to custom object list, @Fields - status,id,version
List<ABC> modifiedRequests =transformToList(myCache.asMap());
modifiedRequests.stream().forEach(nowOrModifiedRequests -> {
    nowOrModifiedRequests.setStatus("xyz");
    myCacheTemp.put(nowOrModifiedRequests.getId,Long.valueOf(nowOrModifiedRequests.getVersion()));
}
myCache.putAll(myCacheTemp);
}
```

Comment: and without the definition, how would someone know what is happening with your code?

Comment: not only definition, but also which cache provider are u using ? also are u using any ORM framework ?

Comment: updated the code. @AntJavaDev, yes, using Hibernate orm and guava for caching

Comment: so i would guess that `ABC` object is a hibernate entity. When you are transforming to list you are not calling the DB again, is that correct? The only case i would think of, is that the entity is still managed, thus hibernate update the value in DB as its being marked as dirty.

Comment: Correct.Any way of modifying the fields without actually updating them back to database as there are multiple fields to be modified.

Comment: Kept my logic in onPreUpdate method to skip DB update for entity. In execute() method, i am able to pass true for skipping the persister.update call but again later on, the method has entry.postUpdate method call which makes an entry to database .
Didn't understand why there are 2 ways of db updates and what is the difference between persister.update method and entry.postupdate in execute method of EntityUpdateAction class. Is there any way of skipping entry.postUpdate call as well. or any other solution for overall issue